# How to use Vuex to store modal component state in child component list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, quasar

I'm trying to use `vuex` to store a value that shows/hides a modal in a child component. The child component is rendered multiple times by its parent in a list. However, the modal is always showing the very last item in the list and I can see that my computed modal value from my vuex state is running the same number of times as the number of elements in the list.

Vuex state

```
export default function () {
  return {
    currentProduct: {},
    allProducts: [],
    editProductDialog: false
  };
}
```

Vuex mutations

```
export const setEditProductDialog = (state, editProductDialog) => {
  state.editProductDialog = editProductDialog
}
```

Parent component:

```
<div>
  <product
    v-for="product in allProducts"
    :key="product.id"
    :product="product"
  />
</div>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
<div class="row justify-start">
  <div class="col-6">
    <q-item clickable v-ripple @click="runSetEditProductDialog">
      <q-item-section avatar>
        <q-icon name="chevron_right" />
      </q-item-section>
      <q-item-section class="text-body1">{{ name }}</q-item-section>
    </q-item>
  </div>
  <q-dialog v-model="editDialog" no-backdrop-dismiss>
     ...
     ...
  </q-dialog>
</template>
...
<script>
export default {
  name: "Product",
  props: ["product"],
  data: () => ({
  }),
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      setEditProductDialog: "product/setEditProductDialog"
    }),
    runSetEditProductDialog() {
      this.setEditProductDialog(true)
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState("product", ["editProductDialog"]),
    editDialog: {
      get() {
        console.log("in get")
        return this.editProductDialog;
      },
       set(value) {
        console.log("in set")
        this.setEditProductDialog(value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Like I said, the dialog always shows the very last `product` component and I can see the print statements in my computed section running the same number of times as the number of elements in `allProducts`.

How do I properly use vuex to store modal state when rendering a list of components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of boolean true/false try to set id:

```
@click="runSetEditProductDialog(product.id)"

runSetEditProductDialog(id) {
  this.setEditProductDialog(id)
},
```

and in your computed property compare it:

```
return this.editProductDialog === this.product.id
```

Comment: this worked and makes a lot of sense. appreciate the clarity!

Comment: @Joe Berg you are welcome mate, cheers :)